# The multipart identifier could not be bound - NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

On the code below I get this error:

> The multipart identifier tblExtraFeature.ProjectId could not be bound

I assume this is a scope problem because the `from tblExtraFeature` is within parens. It works if I remove `tblExtraFeature.ProjectId` from the first line. And yes ProjectId is in tblExtraFeature. I tried assigning an alias to tblExtraFeature, but same problem. How can I get this to work?

```
select tblExtraFeature.ProjectId, tblFeature.FeatureId
  from tblFeature 
  with (NOLOCK)
  where  NOT EXISTS (select *
  from   tblExtraFeature 
    where tblFeature.FeatureId = tblExtraFeature.FeatureId)
```

Edit:
I should have stated this at the outset ... what I'm trying to get is all the rows in tblExtraFeature that are not in tblFeature.

Comment: the outer `SELECT` can't use a directly column from the table you are using in `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: The main question is: what do you want to achieve? What `ProjectId` do you expect in your result; there can be thousands or millions in the `tblExtraFeature` table :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry, see edit to question.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace tblExtraFeature and tblFeature tables with each other. And remove tblFeature.FeatureId from select part.

```
select *
from tblExtraFeature with (NOLOCK)
where NOT EXISTS (select *
from tblFeature  
where 
     tblFeature.FeatureId = tblExtraFeature.FeatureId )
```

Comment: In this case, it is dependent on the * in the first select, i.e. I can't specify `tblFeature.FeatureId` which is I think what @Lamak pointed in his/her comment.

Comment: I know select query has tblFeature.FeatureId but end of question you wrote "I'm trying to get is all the rows in tblExtraFeature that are not in tblFeature".

Comment: And I think your request has some logic error. You are looking for the "tblExtraFeature" rows that are not in the "tblFeature" table. This mean "tblFeature" and "tblExtraFeature" don't have any common rows. And that's why "tblFeature.FeatureId" every time become null.

Answer (score 0):

If tblExtraFeature.FeatureId is a foreign key referencing tblFeature then the rows in tblExtraFeature that are not in tblFeature should be the rows where featureId is null in tblExtraFeature.

Does

```
select * from tblExtraFeature where featureId is null
```

give the result you are looking for?

Comment: All cells of the column tblExtraFeature.FeatureId are populated, so that line returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select * from tblExtraFeature ef
left outer join tblFeature f on f.featureid = ef.featureid
where f.featureid IS NULL
```

Comment: This works if I switch places of tblExtraFeature and tblFeature

Comment: it would be great if you add some description regarding your answer. Kindly avoid just dumping the code only.

Answer (score 0):

> what I'm trying to get is all the rows in tblExtraFeature that are
>   not in tblFeature.

```
SELECT ProjectId, 
       FeatureId
  FROM tblExtraFeature 
  WITH (NOLOCK)
 WHERE FeatureId NOT IN (SELECT FeatureId
                           FROM tblFeature 
                        )
```

Comment: This gives the multipart identifier on FeatureId